# MATLAB 2012 - Create Single list text file from matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I have solved an equation on matlab and have 8760 output data that needs to be put into a single list for excel. that is in Excel A1 to A8760, going down not across.

I have tried the save, fprintf however the data out put does not come out right.

I have only one variable I need and that is 's'

The file name of the resulting text file does not matter. I just need it to be saved as a single list of numbers to examine in excel.

Thank you for reading

Comment: An alternative to `xlswrite` is `csvwrite` or else `dlmwrite`

Comment: @user2845648: If one of the answers below answered your question properly, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`xlswrite('yourdata.xlsx',s)`

Try transposing your vector if your result is horizontal and not vertical. That is:

`xlswrite('yourdata.xlsx',s.')`

See [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the matlab's function `xlswrite` ([doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html)) that will write an array (s) to the first worksheet in Excel file.

Alternatively, Matlab could be used to inspect your array.